# I am not sure if my dpi of my iOS app icon is the right size

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I just recently uploaded my iOS app to apple for submission. I am not sure if the dpi of my app icon is right. When I submitted it, it went through with no problems and right now I am waiting on review. If it was not the correct size or in the right format would it have still gone through? or would it have just told me right when I submitted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine.  If there was anything wrong with the image, a warning would have been given.